# PyCharm does not read full system PATH

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, path, pycharm

#### Context

In Windows 11 the `PATH` environment variable is composed of two `Path` variables: A "user variable" `Path` and a "System variable" `Path`. The actual system path, as returned by eg `echo %%PATH%%`, merges these two variables.

[image]

#### The problem

When running python via a conda environment from within PyCharm, the system path does not reflect the part set by the user variables. E.g., the following will only return the path component set in the system variable:

```
import os
os.getenv("PATH")
```

This is problematic, because many programs such as Miktex will by default register their binaries in the user variable. As a consequence, running for instance `matplotlib` with `text.usetex=True` will fail with an error that `latex` cannot be found. (I suspect that this explains some of the unresolved no latex found problems with `matplotlib` under PyCharm on here)

#### Running Python on the command line

By contrast, running python via the same conda environment directly on the command line, recognizes the complete system path (`os.getenv("PATH")` includes the user path variable), and plotting with matplotlib and latex works as expected.

Is there a way to get PyCharm recognize the user component of the system path so that dependencies work correctly?

Comment: In PyCharm, is Anaconda Python selected as the interpreter? There's a specific option for selecting Anaconda and Anaconda environments.

Comment: Yes, the python interpreter is set to an anaconda environment. The issue is not that the interpreter or the `sys.path` is not working, but that the os path variable is set incorrectly. This matters for python packages that rely on 3rd party dependencies installed on the host system outside of anaconda (such as matplotlib's reliance on latex).

Comment: Maybe you need to modify the [Starting script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oue8P.png) in PyCharm.

Comment: Hm, I have gotten it to work for now by adding "PATH" to the environment variables field on the same settings page as in your screenshot. I don't fully understand why but this seems to have updated the value of the "PATH" environment variable to the correct setting... Will need to monitor more to see whether the fix is persistent

Comment: Incidentally, that is the default setting of PyCharm, at least for several years.

Comment: Right, but what I am not sure is which value it was set before I (re-)added it. After I (re-)added it, opening the little dialog and inspecting the value of `Path` showed both the user and system component, matching the output `os.getenv("PATH")`. Unfortunately, I hadn't checked the value of `Path` in PyCharm's settings prior to (re-)adding, but `os.getenv("PATH")` did only include the system component at that point.